# Kill detached child process in Node

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm not fully understand why I can't kill a detached process. Can someone help me out?

**Server (child process)**

```
const server = spawn(
    'npm',
    [
        'run',
        'watch:be',
    ],
    {
        detached: true,
    },
);
```

**Await for the server to up and running**

```
await waitOn({
    resources: [
        `https://localhost:${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`,
    ],
    delay: 1000,
    timeout: 30000,
});
console.log('server is up and running');
```

**Wait a couple more seconds**

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject): void => {
    setTimeout((): void => {
        resolve();
    }, 2000);
});
console.log('Run test');
```

**Kill the child server**

```
server.kill();
console.log('Shutdown server');
```

All of these are in the same file.

The child process opened a new terminal window (when it does `spawn`, which is expected), but doesn't close when `kill`. Can someone point out what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
server.kill();
```

As per the node.js documentation, The `subprocess.kill()` method sends a signal to the child process. When you use the `detached` option, the node creates a separate process group for the child process and it is not part of the same process anymore.

```
detached <boolean>: Prepare child to run independently of its parent process
```

That is the reason `kill` is not appropriate to use when `detached` is used.

This has been discussed here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2098

As suggested in the above link, you should use `process.kill` to kill the process (https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal). This should probably work for you:

```
process.kill(-server.pid)
```

Comment: if I use `process.kill(-server.pid);`, this will show up `Error: kill ESRCH` :(

Comment: Can you create a small example code so that it can checked?

Comment: If the above isn't working for you, try without the negative: `process.kill(server.pid)`. Negatives are for process groups, not individual processes.

Comment: @manishg I am getting the same error `Error: kill ESRCH` but I am using windows.

Answer (score 0):

You said that "The child process opened a new terminal window ..."

Based on this behaviour, it seems that your OS is Windows.

> On Windows, setting `options.detached` to `true` makes it possible for the child process to continue running after the parent exits. The child will have its own console window. Once enabled for a child process, it cannot be disabled.

[source](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached)

For `process.kill`, the second arg is the signal you want to send. By default, this signal is `SIGTERM`. However, `SIGTERM` doesn't seem to be supported on Windows, according to the [**Signal Events**](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) section of the Node.js docs.

> - `'SIGTERM'` is not supported on Windows, it can be listened on.

Maybe try

```
process.kill(server.pid, 'SIGHUP')
```

or

```
process.kill(server.pid, 'SIGINT')
```

(This works on macOS but I've not tried it on Windows.)

Comment: Just tried both of these on windows. Doesn't seem to work